# hiberante HQL dose not recognize oracle replace function

Tags: function, replace, hql

I have a class

```
       class  A  {
            String aField;
            String bField;
     }

       class  B {
             A   classAField
     }
```

i use restrictions to construct the HQL

```
  Restrictions.like(propertyName, obj);
```

the propertyName i enclosed with a oracle sql funciton to remove all the spaces, so the propertyName is

```
  replace(classAField.aField,' ')
```

and i got the following error

```
  could not resolve property: replace(classAField of: B; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: replace(classAField of: B
```

hiberante cannot recognize pl/sql functions.
   i use oracle 10g diaglect

```
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>

is there a work around here?
```

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

For this, you probably want [`Restrictions.sqlRestriction`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#sqlRestriction%28java.lang.String%29).

Getting it to work in your specific circumstance may take some work, but using it you can usually work around difficulties like this.

Using it for a particular field of a particular entity does not force you to use it everywhere.  It can  be mixed with other restrictions.

Comment: thanks.how to make hiberante use the replace function instead of using sqlRestriction

Comment: You can use it in the arguments to sqlRestriction.

Comment: the problem is i cannot use sqlRestriction for all entities. i need the replace for a particular one attribute of an entity. so i need to know the mapped column name and the table alias name.

Answer (score 0):

ok,  Criterion queries do not recognize functions, except using sqlRestriction